# External Storage Write Access for Kitkat devices

Tags: android, file, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdcard

**The Problem**

My app supports 4.0+ and it is all about file handling. It works perfectly in all Android versions except Kitkat.

In Kitkat, my app is unable to modify or write any files in SD card. But I see various apps like,

1) Solid Explorer
2) ES File Explorer
3) CamScanner
4) UC Browser

All of these apps give write access to SD card even in Kitkat devices without even root access.

**Requirements**

I need to have a fully functional way to create or modify files stored in the SD card in Kitkat. I seems to have troubles a lot of users and a proper solution will help many developers like me.

Comment: ES File Explorer most certainly does not offer this. You can tell by installing and running it on a device that shipped with Android 4.4+ (e.g., SONY Xperia Tablet Z2), then trying to copy a file to removable media. The operation will fail, and the ES File Explorer error dialog will point out that [writing to removable media is not possible](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). I would imagine that the other tools you cite will have the same limitation, as will your app.

Comment: Also, to be clear, [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), from the standpoint of the Android SDK.

Comment: Where my app gets a permission denied trying to write on removable media under kitkat ES File Explorer does it. I like to know too how they do it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot for these amazing series of posts. They have cleared a lot of confusion regarding storage in Android. Thanks a lot for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare But I have just testes now, that in devices like Moto E, Solid Explorer and ES Explorer was able to create, copy, rename, delete files perfectly.

It would be really helpful if you can give us some insight on how they do it? It would be even better if you can help us with some useful code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the Moto E shipped with Android 4.3 or older, the Android 4.4 Compatibility Test Suite rules regarding removable storage would not apply, and my understanding is that removable storage will work as it did on older versions of Android (i.e., undocumented but potentially accessible). It is also possible that there is some security flaw in the Moto E that these apps are exploiting that they cannot on other devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare The Moto E I tested on was shipped with 4.4. I have also tested in 2 more devices - Moto G2 and Xperia L in Kitkat 4.4. In both of these devices, these apps modify SD card content without fail.

I know that Kitkat doesn't permit this and I certainly agree with all your points. But if these apps are working perfectly, then there must be some workaround that we do not know. 

So if we can make use of this, then a lot of developers would get immensely benefited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I came across that problem as well. After a lot of reading across the web the solution is to write only in your app folder (Ex: /sdcard/Android/data/packagename).

About those apps, on my s4 mini, es explorer cannot delete from external sdcard, so I think is different from device to device.

If the devices is routed change the permissions to gain write access anywhere on the sdcard.